# Letters Missing Grid Puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual, letter-sequence

Below is a missing-letter puzzle made by me. You need to find **4** missing letters inside the grid.

[image]

Can you find them?

Hint #1:

> Every row and column has some pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third row:

> $M$ and $N$.

Fifth row:

> $S$ and $U$.

Because in each row and each column,

> taking *alternating* letters (1st, 3rd, 5th and 2nd, 4th, 6th) gives two arithmetic progressions through the alphabet, assuming the alphabet wraps round on itself so that $A=1=27$, $B=2=28$, etc.

Comment: How is that possible ? You are very fast :D ..I need to take some lesson from you :P

Comment: @Swati My instinct in any puzzle like this is to convert letters to numbers and look for patterns. This pattern was relatively easy to spot, especially from the 2nd and last rows.

Comment: Yup .:D ppl here are very intelligent .